# How do i position a div relative to the window page (responsive css)

Tags: jquery, html, css

so i made a button that hides and shows a div with placeholder text:

```
<button id="btn1">Click to display div1</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

the #div1 is positioned as absolute cause i don't want it fixed.

When i click my button how do I make it appear within the window screen? and has 10px top from the window screen?

and additional question how do i center that div?

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twish/UmC8B/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){

  $("#div1").css("top",($(document).scrollTop() + 10) +'px').fadeToggle(); 

});
```

to make div in center

```
#div1{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#007c7c;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    color:white;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px;
}
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UmC8B/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

How's this for you: http://jsfiddle.net/wildandjam/KXW9v/

What I've done is add to #div1:

```
top:10px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-250px;
```

However I think to get the effect of it "popping" up in relation to the window and not the document, you may need to use fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The top value can be put straight to the #div1 css like

```
#div1 {
    top: 10px;
}
```

And because the #div1 is positioned absolute I would calculate the left value for the div like this:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    var leftVal = ($(window).width() - $("#div1").width())/2;
    $("#div1").css("left", leftVal);
    $("#div1").fadeToggle(); 
});
```

So whenever you toggle the button this gets the window width and centers the #div1 relatively to it. It's basicly responsive solution as long as your window width isn't below 500px. I'd recommend using percent value for the #div1 width so even if the window width is smaller than 500px this would work.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UmC8B/4/

Fiddle with responsive #div1 (70%): http://jsfiddle.net/UmC8B/7/

Answer (score 0):

To make it responsive give the width and height in %age for the div and add bottom property for the button in %age. And since I have given the width as 80% for the div just give left property as 10% (10%L + [80%] + 10%R). Hope this is what you want.

```
#div1{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#007c7c;
  width:80%;
  height:25%;
  left: 10%;
  overflow: auto;
  color:white;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UmC8B/6/)

Answer (score -1):

Your div must be positionned as absolute in your CSS file - and if you want to hide it you would also do it in the CSS file linked to your HTML page.
To toggle the div, try:

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#div1").toggle();
});
```

Comment: hey, um sorry i'm not really asking about how to make it appear

Comment: i'm asking about how to position it relatively to the window page